# Unable to create Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

whenever i try to create a cloud function in one of my projects where I HAVE "CLoudFunction.ADMIN" Api permission already. I get a screen asking to enable "Artifact registry API","CLoud Run API","Event arc API". I am unsure what permission is missing ?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zj6z.png)
Attached error

Comment: 1) Did you enable billing for your project? 2) Did you enable the APIs in the message? 3) Your question lacks details.

Comment: Yup I did. Google support let me know what the issue was . The cloud functions have been upgraded to generation 2 . I had the permission cloudfunctions.admin which is only for generation 1 cloud functions. The new generation 2 required cloudfunctions.developer.